# Nutch path error

Tags: solr, nutch, web-crawler

Hi I have installed solr and nutch on Ubuntu. I am able to crawl and index on occassions, but not all the time. I Have been getting this path error repeatedly and could not find a solution online. Usually, I would delete the directories which have errors and rerun, it would run fine. But I dont want to do this anymore. What is causing the error? Thanks.

```
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027231916
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027232907
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027233840
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027224701
LinkDb: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027231916/parse_data
Input path does not exist: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027232907/parse_data
Input path does not exist: file:/home/nutch/nutch/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20111027233840/parse_data
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:175)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.run(LinkDb.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.main(LinkDb.java:255)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have killed a Nutch process. Just clear the directories crawldb etc. and you're good to go.

Nutch first looks for a ready link database (linkdb) in the crawl path, if can't find it, creates a new one from the seed file you give. If you kill a crawling process, this causes that read from the link database fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

Check for the crawl folder exist and has proper permission, and you need to use -linkdb as above as in new version its optional. Mostly this error come due to the path you are specifying for crawldb linkdb and segements path not given correctly.

I had the same problem I used above syntax it worked. Just check the folder you are specifying for these are correct.

Use this,

http://thetechietutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/solr-and-nutch-integration.html

worked for me.